# How can I save the content of object on Array-list?

Tags: arraylist

How can I add the content of object on Array-list?

thanks,

this is my code

```
    ArrayList soft1=new ArrayList();



    if ("Software".equals((String)major.getSelectedItem())){

        add(p2s,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p2s.setVisible(true);
        p2n.setVisible(false);
        p2sc.setVisible(false);
        if (e.getSource()==save){
            String id1=id.getText();
            String name1=name.getText();
            String gender11=(String)gender1.getSelectedItem();
            String major1=(String)major.getSelectedItem();

            StudentSoftware software=new StudentSoftware( studentID, studentName, gender, studentMajor, course1, course2,  course3, mark1, mark2, mark3);
```

Comment: please clear the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the Arraylist with POJO class as `ArrayList<StudentSoftware> soft = new ArrayList<StudentSoftWare>()`. Then Initialize the StudentSoftware as `StudentSoftware student = new StudentSoftware()` the set values to POJOClass as `student .setid(id)` before generate setters and getters in POJOclass. Finally add POJOclass Object to Arraylist as `soft.add(student)`.

I Think Its Useful to U....

Comment: According to the the previous example :How can I represent the content of array-list on text-area or on the console ?

Comment: Again use POJOclass as StudentSofware student = arraylist.get(position) .   then set it to text_area.settext(student.getname()  //Getters method in POJOClass)